# Как настроить и подключиться по ssh к хосту, который находится в другой локальной сети

Tags: hosts

Как настроить хост, чтобы к нему можно было подключиться по ssh с хоста, который находится в другой локальной сети.
И как по ssh подключиться к хосту, который находится в другой локальной сети.
Оба хоста подключены к интернету.
`ssh username@public_ip_adress` не работает.

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. ssh ip_address чем не устраивает?

Comment: @Smithson Что-то не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пробросить порты из одной сети в другую: google://nat, маршрутизация.

как конкретно пробросить порты - зависит от раутера/ос раутера (если раутинг идет через софтовый раутер, а не через интерфейс)
проброс портов нужен для того, чтобы раутер, принимающий сетевой трафик, знал, что соединение на порт 22 нужно отправить одному из конкретных компьютеров в текущей локальной сети.

если сети удаленные, т.е. не соединены раутерами в пределах, условно, одного здания:

если есть доступ к интернету из обеих сетей, но обе стороны не имеют белого ip (доступного извне сети провайдера) - купить vpn доступ/поставить openvpn на свой хостинг и соединяться по адресам виртуальной сети.

на одном из компьютеров/раутеров в обеих сетях у вас будет установлен vpn-клиент, он будет раздавать трафик из виртуальной сети остальным компьютерам (если доступ нужен более чем одному компьютеру)

гуглите так: "соединить сети через интернет vpn" (еще лучше на английском, там лучше инструкции) - поскольку детали тоже зависят от ос/схем подключения (наличие белого айпи) и т.д.

Comment: Для чего нужен проброс портов? И должно ли работать подлючение к локальному хосту через публичный ip-адресс?

Comment: через публичный ip адрес оно  будет работать, если комп напрямую подключен к проводу от провайдера - если не подключен, надо пробросить порт от раутера (в его настройках) к какому-нибудь из компьютеров (google://nat название раутера) ну и да, надо убедиться, что фаервол разрешает доступ через эти порты. И да, рекомендую сменить порты ssh-серверов с 22 (и на раутере тоже) на что-нибудь другое, так слегка меньше вероятность взлома

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш хост находится только в локальной сети, то и подключиться вы к нему сможете только из этой локальной сети.

Comment: Доступ к интернету с обоих хостов тоже есть.